# Communicating information about functions in plain English.

Tags: functions

I am having a bit of trouble with communicating information about functions in  English. I know that $f(x)$ is read $f$ of $x$, but how would I use this in a sentence? Say, we have a argument x=5, and I want to express the process of passing this input to the function, would I then say:

- taking $f$ of 5 gives $f(5) = 5^2+1$,
- putting the argument $x=5$ gives $f(5) = 5^2+1$ (this seems ambiguous if multiple functions exists), or
- putting $x=5$ and applying function $f$ gives $f(5) = 5^2+1$?

I suspect that the first option is correct, but English is not my native language and I'd love some feedback on this.

Comment: The first two bullet points should have "gives" instead of "give".  The first one would then be fine. It seems you're trying to say something in a slightly unnatural way though, I'd say "when its argument is 5, $f$ takes the value $5^2+1$" or "applying the function $f$ to 5 gives $5^2+1$" or just "$f$ applied to 5 gives $5^2+1$".

Comment: thank you for the input, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluating the function $f$ at the point $x=5$ gives $f(5)=5^2+1$.